# Merge 2 Adapter , and show it in one listview android

Tags: android, listview

i'm looking for a way to merge two adapters into one `listview`, 
this is my code that show two adapter in two `listview`, is there any possibility to merge it ?

```
not_choose.clear();   
ArrayList<dec_all> a = this.notchoose();
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {

    int tidno = a.get(i).getid();
    String name = a.get(i).getname();
    dec_all cnt = new dec_all();
    cnt.setid(tidno);
    cnt.setname(name);

    not_choose.add(cnt);
}
dbHandler.close();
gtpAdapter = new not_chooseadapter(this, R.layout.not_choose_listrow,
        not_choose);


i_choose.clear();
ArrayList<dec_all> b = this.ichoose();

for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++) {

    int tidno = b.get(i).getid();
    String name = b.get(i).getname();
    dec_all cnt = new dec_all();
    cnt.setid(tidno);
    cnt.setname(name);

    i_choose.add(cnt);
}
dbHandler.close();
gtAdapter = new i_chooseadapter(this, R.layout.i_choose_listrow,
        i_choose);

lvdata_one.setAdapter(gtAdapter); //listview one
lvdata_two.setAdapter(gtpAdapter); //list view two
```

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Combine two array list into a  one:

```
List<String> listA = new ArrayList<String>();
listA.add("A");

List<String> listB = new ArrayList<String>();
listB.add("B");

List<String> listFinal = new ArrayList<String>();
listFinal.addAll(listA);
listFinal.addAll(listB);
```

Or you can append to listB
like this :

```
listB.addAll(listA);
```